# When I set the anchor point, my image is not loading

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I have a UIView on which i am loading my image view as a sub view. The image is showing when i doesn't set the anchor point but whenever i set anchor point the image is not showing .I have added the QUARTZCore frame work also.

I am adding my code below

```
CGRect apprect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:apprect1];
containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];

handleView1= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"large.gif"]];
[handleView1 setAlpha:1];
//[handleView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(390, 172.00, 56.00, 316.00)];
handleView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
handleView1.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(490.0, 172.0);
[containerView addSubview:handleView1];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem are the values you use for the anchorPoint. You don't set points like for the position of a frame as values. Let me quote Apple:

> The anchorPoint property is a CGPoint
>   that specifies a location within the
>   bounds of a layer that corresponds
>   with the position coordinate. The
>   anchor point specifies how the bounds
>   are positioned relative to the
>   position property, as well as serving
>   as the point that transforms are
>   applied around. **It is expressed in
>   the unit coordinate system-the
>   (0.0,0.0) value is located closest to
>   the layer’s origin and (1.0,1.0) is
>   located in the opposite corner.**

[image]

Have a look at [Layer Geometry and Transforms in the Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW15) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

First set the Frame of your ImageView and then set the ancherpoint like this

[ handleView1.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1)];